# stdweb::web::html_element::CanvasElement from document().query_selector() in Rust

Tags: canvas, rust, yew

I am building a Yew webapp in Rust, and attempting to get a CanvasRenderingContext2d from a CSS selector. The issue I am having is how to convert a `stdweb::web::Element` into a `stdweb::web::html_element::CanvasElement`.

My current code is this:

```
use stdweb::web::{CanvasRenderingContext2d, document, Element, IParentNode};
use stdweb::web::html_element::CanvasElement;

fn get_canvas_context(selector: &str) -> CanvasRenderingContext2d {
    let element: Element = document().query_selector(selector)
        .expect(format!("query_selector({selector}) not found").as_str())
        .unwrap()
    ;
    // BUG: the trait `From<stdweb::web::Element>` is not implemented for `CanvasElement`
    let canvas_element: CanvasElement = element
        .try_into()
        .expect(format!("query_selector({selector}) not CanvasElement").as_str())
    ;
    let context: CanvasRenderingContext2d = canvas_element.get_context()
        .expect(format!("query_selector({selector}) failed to get_context()").as_str())
    ;
    context
}
```

`cargo check` reports the following error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `CanvasElement: From<stdweb::web::Element>` is not satisfied
  --> src/utils.rs:12:10
   |
12 |         .try_into()
   |          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<stdweb::web::Element>` is not implemented for `CanvasElement`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<CanvasElement>` for `stdweb::web::Element`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::TryFrom<stdweb::web::Element>` for `CanvasElement`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::TryInto<CanvasElement>` for `stdweb::web::Element`
```

My ultimate goal is to return a `CanvasRenderingContext2d` which I assume requires `canvas_element.get_context()`

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `dyn_into`:

```
  let canvas = document
    .get_element_by_id("my-canvas")
    .unwrap()
    .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement>()?;
```

More info in the [`JsCast`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html) docs.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ben for inspiring me with your answer above.

The code was a little more complex to implement in practice than your code snippit suggested. However your hint to use `.dyn_into()` from [JsCast](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html) allowed me to search github for more code examples.

After a few days of effort, I was finally able to get the following code snippit to compile and render:

- Inspiration: https://github.com/jessaimaya/rust_wasm/blob/89cea2a7aea240f6bd3ec8722e539aca35cee73c/src/browser.rs
- Source: https://github.com/JamesMcGuigan/fractals/blob/1c5d8bbf5cee6f02536205cd9036f71597f523f1/src/html/canvas_context.rs

```rust
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
use web_sys::{CanvasRenderingContext2d, Document, HtmlCanvasElement, Window};

#[allow(dead_code)]
// DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window
pub fn window() -> Result<Window> {
    web_sys::window()
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("No Window Found"))
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
// DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document
pub fn document() -> Result<Document> {
    window()?
        .document()
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("No Document Found"))
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
// DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HtmlCanvasElement
pub fn canvas(id_selector: &str) -> Result<HtmlCanvasElement> {
    document()?
        .get_element_by_id(id_selector)
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("No Canvas Element found with ID 'canvas'"))?
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement>()
        .map_err(|element| anyhow!("Error converting {:#?} to HtmlCanvasElement", element))
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
// DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2d
pub fn canvas_context_2d(id_selector: &str) -> Result<CanvasRenderingContext2d> {
    canvas(id_selector)?
        .get_context("2d")
        .map_err(|js_value| anyhow!("Error getting 2d context {:#?}", js_value))?
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("No 2d context found"))?
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::CanvasRenderingContext2d>()
        .map_err(|element| {
            anyhow!(
                "Error converting {:#?} to CanvasRenderingContext2d",
                element
            )
        })
}
```